# dropdown list in navigation bar does not work and get an error

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

i have a project using bootstrap and jQuery and when i put the code of navigation it give me that error in console:

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: i.createPopper is not a function
    at xt._createPopper (bootstrap.min.js:6:23887)
    at xt.show (bootstrap.min.js:6:22196)
    at xt.toggle (bootstrap.min.js:6:22024)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6:26602)
    at HTMLDocument.s (bootstrap.min.js:6:4510) :
```

i am trying to use jQuery version : 2.2.1 and 1.12.4 .

Comment: Extra details should go in the question itself - click the link marked "edit", not the one marked "add comment".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be missing the popper.js on your project. Add it by using CDN below:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And see the documentation of [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) if you want to include both files with one script call.